# Is any rational extension of degree 3 of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, cubics

If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is an extension of degree $2$, then necessarily it is of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. So, I am wondering if a similar philosophy holds for extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree 3.

Comment: @RhythmInk, I am asking that if $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is an extension s.t $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=3$ then there exists $d$ cubfree s.t $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$?

Comment: My mistake. I don't know what I was thinking. It's been deleted.

Comment: Would you consider $\mathbb{Q}\left(e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}\right)$ to be of the given form $\left(e^\frac{2i\pi}{3}\right)^3 = 1$, but we generally wouldn't say it's $\sqrt[3]{1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer I think should be negative because if, for example, $\theta$ is the real root of $x^3+x+1=0$ then $K=\mathbb Q(\theta)$ is of degree $3$ but $\theta\approx -0.6823$ being such that $\theta^3+\theta+1=0$ is not of the form you asked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: It is a pleasure for me. You are welcome.

Comment: How do you know $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)\neq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$ for some $d\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$ is not a Galois extension if $d$ is not a power of $3$. In fact, it is not normal, there exists Galois extensions of degree $3$,therefore they cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb({Q}\sqrt[3]{d})$.

[Finding a Galois extension of $\Bbb Q$ of degree $3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2112332/finding-a-galois-extension-of-bbb-q-of-degree-3)